# Config for Parallel Testing in Artos

Tags: unit-testing, automation, automated-tests, artos

I am trying to test 5 hardware in parallel using Artos parallel suite feature. Is there a way for me to pass hardware specific info to each test suite, It must not mix up the info because based on com port and serial number, I would perform different tests on it.
For Example: each hardware require following unique information:

- Serial number
- Com port
- Flash size
- and string pattern
- outcome

I also update some of these information on the fly.
I tried to read/write properties file per hardware but looking for more scallable and efficient solution. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in the test script area.
Each test suite specified in the test script shall execute distinctively in parallel. 
These test suites can have either the same or different test cases in them as per need.
These test suites carry parameters which are available at run time i.e they are global variables, 
thus these variables can be used for passing your hardware related values.

Below is an example script to replicate your scenario:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration version="1">

  <suite loopcount="1" name="TestSuite1">
    <tests>
      <test name="com.featureX.TestCase_1"/>
      <test name="com.featureY.TestCase_2"/>
    </tests>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="SerialNumber">123</parameter>
      <parameter name="ComPort">12345</parameter>
      <parameter name="FlashSize">256</parameter>
 <parameter name="AndStringPattern">&&</parameter>
 <parameter name="Outcome">ABC123</parameter>
    </parameters>
    <testcasegroups>
      <group name="*"/>
    </testcasegroups>
    <testunitgroups>
      <group name="*"/>
    </testunitgroups>
  </suite>

  <suite loopcount="1" name="TestSuite2">
    <tests>
      <test name="com.featureA.TestCase_1"/>
      <test name="com.featureB.TestCase_2"/>
    </tests>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="SerialNumber">456</parameter>
      <parameter name="ComPort">67890</parameter>
      <parameter name="FlashSize">512</parameter>
 <parameter name="AndStringPattern">&</parameter>
 <parameter name="Outcome">ABC12345</parameter>
    </parameters>
    <testcasegroups>
      <group name="*"/>
    </testcasegroups>
    <testunitgroups>
      <group name="*"/>
    </testunitgroups>
  </suite>
 
  <suite loopcount="1" name="TestSuite3">
    <tests>
      <test name="com.featureP.TestCase_1"/>
      <test name="com.featureQ.TestCase_2"/>
 <test name="com.featureP.TestCase_3"/>
 <test name="com.featureQ.TestCase_4"/>
    </tests>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="SerialNumber">PQ123</parameter>
      <parameter name="ComPort">12345</parameter>
      <parameter name="FlashSize">256</parameter>
 <parameter name="AndStringPattern">&&</parameter>
 <parameter name="Outcome">PQ123</parameter>
    </parameters>
    <testcasegroups>
      <group name="*"/>
    </testcasegroups>
    <testunitgroups>
      <group name="*"/>
    </testunitgroups>
  </suite>
 
  <suite loopcount="1" name="TestSuite4">
   //your settings here
  </suite>
 
  <suite loopcount="1" name="TestSuite5">
   //your settings here
  </suite>

</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.